# Daterangepicker not opening on click in AngularJS

Tags: jquery, angularjs, bootstrap-4

I am working on an application based on AngularJS, JQuery and Bootstrap. I have placed a custom daterangepicker [www.daterangepicker.com](http://www.daterangepicker.com/).

**Problem**: The problem is that when i click on daterangepicker it does not get opened but gets opnened only when i change the page and returns back or when i insert alert in the code so as to hold its focus.

**Below are the code files for better understanding**

**test.html**

```
<div class="date-range-support-div">
  <input type="text" name="daterange" value="" ng-click="glElmDb.openRangePicker()" id="daterange"/> 
</div>
```

**test.js**

```
    // writing custom code for date range picker
    glElmDb.openRangePicker = function () {
        alert('');
        $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
            opens: 'left'
        }, function (start, end, label) {
            console.log("A new date selection was made: " + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' to ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
        });
    }
```

**screenshot**
[image: daterangepicker not opening when alert is not there]

[image]

[image: daterangerpicker opens when alert is present]

**any solution please ?**

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$scope.$applyAsync()` after you set the dateRangePicker as open:

```
    // writing custom code for date range picker
    glElmDb.openRangePicker = function () {
        alert('');
        $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
            opens: 'left'
        }, function (start, end, label) {
            console.log("A new date selection was made: " + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' to ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
        });
        $scope.$applyAsync();
    }
```

Explanation:
since you're using jQuery for your date picker, AngularJS isn't aware you clicked it, so it doesn't automatically refresh the frontend for you. By using $applyAsync, you manually trigger an [Angular digest cycle](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#scope-life-cycle).

Comment: hi Caio Costa, I tried with the code you provided, but the problem is that the daterangepicker gets open and close immediately.